# Очень много запущенных процессов

Tags: linux

Перезагрузил сервер, зашёл в htop и понеслась...

Как убрать лишние процессы?

```
[root@GameServers ~]# uname -a
Linux GameServers 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 13 00:26:49 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Как избавиться от этого?

```
...
   2     root     18:10     [kthreadd]
   3     root     18:10     [migration/0]
   4     root     18:10     [ksoftirqd/0]
   5     root     18:10     [migration/0]
   6     root     18:10     [watchdog/0]
...
```

Система: Centos 6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да ничего не изменилось, то что в квадратных скобках это процессы ядра. Нажмите "К" и вы их не уведите. И да, их лучше не убирать)

Answer (score 1):

Чем-то мешает ? У вас видимо 8 ядер (по одному процессу каждого типа на ядро). Каждый из этих процессов - ядерный, памяти они не едят, нужны чтобы отслеживать внутрисистемные проблемы, типа i/o.  Для более точного описания каждого вида обратитесь к документации на ядро вашей версии. (2.6.32 - старенькое ядро кстати, сейчас половины из этих процессов не видно)

Comment: Изменилась версия ядра. Чем мешает кол-во процессов ? Вас должно волновать io wait, load average расход памяти. Может есть какой-то ключ при загрузке чтобы скрывать их, никогда не интересовался, а сейчас у меня 3.2

Comment: @pyatak прокоментируйте, вы например даже не указали что имеете ввиду top. а-то может K нажать где угодно ? :)

Comment: ТС в вопросе изначально указал чем он пользуется (htop ага), если он конечно "К" просто в терминале нажмет, то уж не сломает ничего по крайней мере)

Comment: минус за что ?

Comment: За 8 ядер , у него скорее всего 8 файловых систем.

Comment: ссылку на доку

Comment: Не будет ссылки, вы правы. Извиняюсь, минус забираю обратно.

Answer (score 0):

Ядро установилось само. Собирать отдельно(лично под себя) - пока не вижу смысла. Раньше этих процессов не было видно. Что изменилось?